# System of differential equation (Matrix form)

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this system

$$
M\ddot{X}(t) = KX(t)
$$

where M is a known diagonal matrix and K is a symmetrical known matrix. I'm asked to do the ansatz $Y(t) = M^{1/2}X(t)$ where $M^{1/2} = diag(\sqrt{m_1},...,\sqrt{m_N})$ so that it takes the new form $\ddot{Y}(t)=AY(t)$, can someone show me what they mean by that? Why not just multiply with $M^{-1}$ from the left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such ansatz makes sure that your $A$ is still symmetric. If you just multiply by $M^{-1}$, you will not have a symmetric matrix on the right-hand side of the equation.

Here's how the given ansatz works:
\begin{align}
M\frac{d^2}{dt}X & = KX \\
M^{1/2}\frac{d^2}{dt}\left(M^{1/2}X\right) & = KX \\
\frac{d^2}{dt}\left(M^{1/2}X\right) & = M^{-1/2}KM^{-1/2}\left(M^{1/2}X\right) \\
\therefore \frac{d^2}{dt}Y & = AY
\end{align}
where $Y = M^{1/2}X$ and $A = M^{-1/2}KM^{-1/2}$. $A$ is symmetric because $K$ is.

Comment: Ooh, now I get it! I was taking it for granted that multiplying with the inverse of M would give me a symmetric matrix but this makes more sense.Thank you very much!

Comment: Just a follow up question. If I have  a diagonal matrix M, doesn't that make $M^{-1}K$ symmetric as well? If M isn't diagonal I get the point but in this special case we have right here I could have just done it this way right?

Comment: @Danny No. Multiplying $M^{-1}$ to the left of $K$ scales rows of $K$ according to the diagonal elements of $M^{-1}$. This will destroy the symmetry unless all diagonal elements of $M^{-1}$ are equal.

Comment: yes ofc, thanks!